# Akka Consistent-hashing routing

Tags: akka, akka-typed, consistent-hashing

I have developed an application using Typed Akka 2.6.19.

I want to route events from a certain source to the SAME routee/worker based on IP address. So, I have planned to use Consistent-hashing routing.

I do not see much literature on this route type for Typed akka. Please give some pointers & example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only to initialize the router with the hash function to use.

For example (in Scala, though the Java API will be similar):

```scala
trait Command {
  // all commands are required to have an associated IP Address (here represented in string form)
  def ipAddr: String
}

// inside, e.g. the guardian actor, and using the actor context to spawn the router as a child
val serviceKey = ServiceKey[Command]("router")
val router = context.spawn(
  Routers.group(serviceKey)
    .withConsistentHashingRouting(
      virtualNodesFactor = 10,
      mapping = { msg: Command => msg.ipAddr }
    )

// spawn the workers, who will register themselves with the router
val workerBehavior =
  Behaviors.setup[Command] { ctx =>
    ctx.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(serviceKey, context.self)

    Behaviors.receiveMessage { msg =>
      ??? // TODO
    }
  }

(1 to 10).foreach { i =>
  context.spawn(workerBehavior, s"worker-$i")
}
```

Under the hood, for every worker that registers, the router will then generate `10` (the `virtualNodesFactor`) random numbers and associate them with that worker.  The router will then execute the `mapping` function for every incoming message to get a string key for the message, which it will hash.  If there is a worker with an associated random number less than or equal to that hash, the worker the greatest associated random number which is also less than or equal to that hash is selected; if the hash happens to be less than every random number associated with any worker, the worker with the greatest associated random number is selected.

Note that this implies that a given worker may process messages for more than 1 `ipAddr`.

Note that this algorithm does not make a strong guarantee that commands with the same `ipAddr` will always go to the same worker, even if the worker they were routed to is still active: if another worker registers and has a token generated which is greater than the previous worker's relevant token and that generated token is less than the hash of `ipAddr`, that new worker will effectively steal the messages for that `ipAddr` from the old worker.

The absence of this guarantee in turn means that if you depend for correctness on all messages for a given `ipAddr` to go to the same worker, you'll want something like cluster sharding, which is higher overhead but allows something a guarantee that no worker will ever see messages for multiple `ipAddr`s and (especially with persistence) will guarantee that the same "logical actor"/entity handles messages for the same `ipAddr`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Levi for the elaborate explanation. You have mentioned two issues. The first issue is that "given worker may process messages for more than 1 ipAddr". If I set the virtualNodesFactor same as the number of workers, will the issue still occur? Please clarify.

Comment: The second issue is that "commands with the same ipAddr will always go to the same worker". If spawn required workers in one shot and register with the Receptionist, will this issue still happen? Please clarify.

Comment: I have coded in Java going by your suggestion and uploaded it to https://github.com/murthy-nn/ConsistentHashingRouting-V2. I have tried different approaches to make it work. But, no success. + In case of groupRouter_v2a, I see an exception "Actor ... was created with wrong ActorContext" and eventually the worker actor was terminated.  + Whereas, in case of the version groupRouter_v2b & groupRouter_v2c, I see one specific type of message StartEventProcessing is routed to EventWorker, whereas StopEventProcessing is not routed to EventWorker.

Comment: In the example Scala code, I see the variable router is unused. How are the workers associated with the router?

Comment: Should the virtualNodesFactor be the same as the number of workers for hashing without any collision? I mean one-to-one mapping between hash value and worker?

Comment: Consistent hash routing cannot guarantee no collisions.

Comment: The workers register with the router by sending the message to the receptionist.  Note that there is no guarantee when the router will see the registration.

Comment: As for `groupRouter_v2a`, the issue is https://github.com/murthy-nn/ConsistentHashingRouting-V2/blob/d71f5224b3ecf4f6c2ba8627b69caa64a0656a62/src/main/java/akka/EventRouter.java#L55 the `this` you're returning is the `EventRouter`, not the worker.

Comment: Your `EventWorker` seems to never stop processing the `StartEventProcessing` command, so thus never processes the `StopEventProcessing` command.

Comment: Thank you for a super quick response. You are right  EventWorker does not process StopEventProcessing as StartEventProcessing  is running in an infinite loop based on a flag processEventFlag which is a local variable. I am confirming this after testing the required code changes.

Comment: Event loop runs in an infinite loop based on a flag. When we need to exit the loop, we set the flag. In the case of multi-threaded applications, the flag is passed to the threads as SHARED object. Event loop runs in one thread and another thread will set the flag to false whenever it wants to stop the Event loop. How to achieve this in Actor model? Would not sharing the objects/state goes against Actor model? Please clarify

Comment: Another query: when the EventRouter try to pass a message to EventWorker through "tell", Akka should call the registered mapping method namely "msg -> msg.getDevice().getIp()" (https://github.com/murthy-nn/ConsistentHashingRouting-V2/blob/main/src/main/java/model/Device.java#L19). However, I do not see the control reaching the mapping method for either of the messages StartEventProcessing or StopEventProcessing. When does the mapping method called?

Comment: In a pure actor model, all interprocess communication is by message sending.  Since Akka is built on a runtime (the JVM) which exposes threads and other concurrency primitives (e.g. futures), it's possible though often not advised to mix-and-match concurrency primitives (not advised because it often means incorporating the union of the limitations of the primitives, e.g. having to use `synchronized` in an actor).

Comment: In a pure actor model, each iteration of the event loop could be triggered by a message to self (the sleep could be replaced by scheduling that message to self: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#scheduling-messages-to-self); setting `processEventFlag` would then just be a matter of sending a message to that effect to the worker.

Comment: The mapping function gets called on every message send to the router.

Comment: Thanks @LeviRamsey. I temporarily introduced sleep in the event loop. In reality, there would be a blocking call to fetch events one by one from the network device.

Comment: You suggested replacing each iteration of the event loop with a self message so that the EventWorker will process the message StopEventProcessing which in turn will set the flag processEventFlag and eventually stop the Event Processing. But, would not this be an expensive procedure with so many messages?

Comment: Because of the infinite loop, the EventWorker does not process any message sent to it, StopEventProcessing in my case. From this behavior, I see a fundamental difference in the way the CPU is allocated to threads and actors. In the case of threads, each thread is allocated a time slice. So, even when a thread is in an infinite loop based on a flag, the flag could be set in between. Whereas, an actor which is in an infinite loop based on a flag would not process any message sent say to change the flag. Why is the difference in the way CPU is allocated to threads and actors?

Comment: Local messages are cheap in Akka.  Under the hood in Akka are threads managed as part of a dispatcher (a finite number of threads).  While an actor is processing a message (that is to say between when the `Behavior` is handed a message by the dispatcher and when it returns the `Behavior` to use for processing the next message), it occupies a thread.  The dispatcher in turn ensures that the actor only processes one message at a time.

Comment: You mention a "blocking call to fetch events".  You will almost certainly get better results by only performing that call in a separate dispatcher (thus a separate thread pool) from the actors processing the events: see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/dispatchers.html#blocking-management

Comment: It's not that far off to view the actors running in a particular dispatcher as cooperatively multitasking (owning CPU until an explicit yield) rather than pre-emptively multitasking (something external inserting yields).  Cooperative can be more efficient due to control over context switches.